# Can UK student visa refusal impact on Australian Student visa application?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, visa-refusals, australia

I have been recently refused (3 weeks ago) student visa application that I applied for UK and the refusal reasons were based on my credibility interview where the ECO asked me detailed ranking questions about my chosen university (which they are not suppose to ask) and he believed I wasn’t a genuine student.

I have hence submitted the appeal and it’s taking longer than I expected and still in the process. Classes are due to start 28 jan and I don’t think I will have any response quicker than few months means I will miss the session and will probably be enrolled again for September session which is too late for my 2 years holiday leave.

I seek to apply for Australia now as I can’t wait for UK anymore. They refused me with stupid reasons that completely shows if they don’t like someone they won’t give away their visas.

Now in Australian visa form they are asking about the visa refusal from any other country.

Do I need to say yes as my application is still in an appeal process?

If I say no do they check each application and are their immigration system linked to UK?

I feel so impotent at this time as I am a genuine student wishing to get my MBA from UK/Australia and despite of big bank balance and all documents in place I simply can’t do it!! It’s frustrating.

I would like someone’s advise on it please.

I have not applied for Australia yet but seriously thinking of applying and gathering all sorts of information and documents I need.

The image of the refusal:

[image]

---

When discussed with university they raised the issue with their account manager at the immigration.

They were not suppose to ask questions about rankings and comparisons with other institutes which I was told before the interview so of course when asked at the beginning of the interview I was shocked and lost all my confidence for the rest of 15 mins.

My university is quite sure they will overturn the decision but I am not sure when and even if they will. I only have 2 years for MBA and I have already wasted 3 months!

Regarding the interview itself, although it started well I began to feel the officer was losing patience and cutting me off in mid-sentence, which caused me to lose confidence and I genuinely felt uncomfortable.

Waiting for appeal decision to come through which will probably take 30-60 days!

Comment: The UK and Australia (along with USA, New Zealand and Canada) do share immigration information under the ‘five eyes’ intelligence treaty. Whether that automatically means information relating to your case will be available to Australia is hard to say, but the best approach is always to tell the truth in any visa application.

Comment: Thank you Traveller. That’s what I thought. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What reason were you given for your refusal? I'm quite sure it wasn't _"I don't like this person."_ and I doubt it was as 'stupid' as you say.  If you don't address that then you're likely to be refused a visa by Australia as well. Post a photo of your refusal letter with personal information blanked out and someone may be able to help. Note that questions about student visas should really be asked on [expatriates.se]

Comment: I would like to ask did you get the turn over in your administrative review? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

> I would like someone’s advise on it please.

The best advice would probably be you to print out the refusal letter, togeather with your question and to recongnize why the interviewer considered you **not credible** after the **credibility interview**.

Some points, I believe, you should **not repeat** in any future interview are listed below.

---

You  claim:

> the ECO asked me detailed ranking questions about my chosen university (**which they are not suppose to ask**)

- who says that during a **credibility interview** ranking questions cannot be asked?

You yourself brought the topic up when answering a compleatly different question:

> When asked why did you choose this institute you said
>
> > Kingston University - I found the Kingston business school is one of one of the few 120 business schools which have been awarded [AACSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_to_Advance_Collegiate_Schools_of_Business) accreditation.
>
> When you were then asked what does AACSB stands for you said
>
> > "I am not sure."

At this point it is clear to the interviewer, that you are using the term **AACSB** as the **reason** for the choice of Kingston University

- without knowing what **AACSB** is

Do you really believe that is credible?

> Also when asked what advantage did this institute have over the other institutes you considered you said
>
> > "Their teaching quality is better, they have excellent rating compared to Hertfordshire."

Here you make a clear statement, based on your research, that Kingston University is better than Hertfordshire based on the ratings.

> You were then asked what is the rating for Hertfordshire and you said
>
> > "I might not know exactly but **there wasn't that accreditation of this when I looked at the website**.

Here you **contradict** yourself by admitting that you found nothing about the Hertfordshire ratings to compare with Kingston ratings.

> The points above show a lack of research and knowledge in your field of study and on the institute you have chosen. You have stated an AACSB award as a positive and as a reason for why you chose this institute yet cannot say what the acronym stands for.

Had you stated something in the form of:

> > Based on the AACSB rating value for Kingston, as apposed to Hertfordshire (where I could find no value to judge by), I believe that Kingston is the better choise for me.

The interviewer may have possibly come to a completely different conclusion.

---

The third question asks you what the Kingston course will offer you that will assist in your future professional life.

> When asked how does this course help you achieve your future plans you said
>
> > "I have done MBA Marketing hand have six years' experience and I leamt a lot from diverse cultures but I believe that my previous studies were not enough to raise my expertise to a higher level so I need to start with a new degree and I think that this course has it all. I found that this course will help
> >     me in to the big lime especially the work placement year which will really add to my CV as I will have UK experience."

- the interviewer still has no idea (nor I) what the the Kingston course is offering you to achive your goals

  - and comes to the conclusion that you don't either

> This is a general response and doesn't answer the question put to you. This leads me to further doubt your credibility as a genuine student.

Had you given a few details of what the Kingston course is offering, then the interviewer may have, again, have come to another conclusion.

---

> Now in Australian visa form they are asking about the visa refusal from any other country.

Since the result of the **credibility interview** was stated as:

> > I am therefore not satisfied you are a genuine student and **refuse your application** under paragraph 245ZV(k) of the Immigration Rules.

This is a refusal and thus must be stated in the Australian visa form.
Assume that they will also want to see the refusal letter.

For an Australian **credibility interview** make sure that

- you don't use terms that you can't explain

  - AACSB is a rating to assist in judging the quality of an university
- clear goals of what the chosen University is offering you

  - showing that this university offers that what you are looking to achieve

This is what the interviewers are looking for.
Doing so conveniently in the second interview may offset the bad impression of the first interview.

Interviewers know that people are nervous and expect it.
They do this every day and therefore have practical experience on how people react.

But they also can also distinguish between those who have a good idea of what they want to achieve and those who come completely unprepared.

---

**Sources**:

- [Association to Advance Collegiate Schools of Business](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_to_Advance_Collegiate_Schools_of_Business)

Comment: Hi Mark Johnson. I am so grateful for you to write the response in such a detail and very clearly. 
I will print your response and work our the mistakes I did and will prepare myself properly for Australia. 

I’m so thankful for you again. 

Kind regards